# How to Delete phone number from contact in android?

Tags: android, contacts, android-cursor

I want to delete (e.g. mobile number) from android database. For that I am passing query as follow

```
public class ContactDemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String number = "2222";
        Long id = getID(number);
        int i = getContentResolver().delete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, RawContacts._ID+"=?", new String[]{id.toString()});
       System.out.println("Deleted"+i);
    }
    public Long getID(String number){       

        Uri uri =  Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
        Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            return c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

but it is deleting entire contact.

What should I use to delete only that phone number (not entire contact)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the delete method of the ContentResolver so you delete the whole contact. To update the phone number of this contact to an empty value, you need to use the ContactsContact API.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

By providing the contact raw id and a Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, you can request only for phone number belonging to this contact and then remove all of them.

```
 ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = Lists.newArrayList();
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Data.CONTENT_URI)
          .withSelection(Data._ID + "=? and " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId), Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
          .build());
 getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```